# How do I serve and distribute a Mac Keynote file from linux?

Tags: linux, mac, iwork-keynote

Mac keynotes are directories.  When double clicked on OS X, the files are opened in the Mac Keynote application.  I want to distribute those keynote files from a web site. How do I package it so that it can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it into a zip archive.

You might also find the following interesting: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=865246